# Couldn't install dependencies while setting up strapi project

Tags: npm, content-management-system, strapi

`npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart`
I am executing this command and it is trying to download certain libraries from github using npm. Due to security reasons the servers are not allowed access to github, so it is not able to download libraries like *libvips*. Is there any other way to setup a strapi project so that it could get libraries from any other source ?
Here's the error snippet

```
npx: installed 91 in 18.847s
Creating a new Strapi application at /home/centos/my-project.

Creating a quickstart project.
Creating files.
Error while installing dependencies:
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated boom@7.3.0: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/boom. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated @formatjs/intl-unified-numberformat@3.3.7: We have renamed the package to @formatjs/intl-numberformat
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@3.12.0: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@3.10.0: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
info sharp Downloading http://10.157.194.58/sharp/v8.10.0/libvips-8.10.0-linux-x64.tar.br
ERR! sharp tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
../src/common.cc:24:22: fatal error: vips/vips8: No such file or directory
#include <vips/vips8>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/centos/node-v12.18.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/home/centos/node-v12.18.4-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/centos/node-v12.18.4-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/centos/my-project/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.4","npm":"6.14.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN strapi-connector-bookshelf@3.2.2 requires a peer of knex@^0.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @buffetjs/utils@3.3.1 requires a peer of yup@^0.27.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.26.0 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.26.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/centos/.npm/_logs/2020-10-09T11_07_28_305Z-debug.log

Keep trying!

Oh, it seems that you encountered errors while installing dependencies in your project.
Don't give up, your project was created correctly.
Fix the issues mentionned in the installation errors and try to run the following command:

cd /home/centos/my-project && npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

This helps for me.

Open MAC terminal and use these commands:

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npx create-strapi-app`
3. `npm i`
4. `npm run develop`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md#Solutions

After, that still had problem with installation and deleted `.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.10.0-darwin-x64.tar.br` file and installed `npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart` everything was ok

Answer (score 0):

i have problem in installing dependencies
my operation system is windows 11
tested with node v14 and v16
tested with npm v6 and v8
tested with yarn npx and npm
no one working
i just stuck in line bellow for hours

```
warning "@strapi/strapi > @strapi/admin > webpack-dev-server > http-proxy-middleware@2.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "@types/express@^4.17.13".
warning "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions > grant-koa@5.4.8" has unmet peer dependency "koa@>=2.0.0". 
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
[-/9] ⠠ waiting...
[-/9] ⠠ waiting...
[-/9] ⠠ waiting...
[4/9] ⠠ sharp
[-/9] ⠐ waiting...
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was as simple as adding a `yarn.lock` file to the root of your project and running `yarn install` and finally run `yarn start`, your project should start successfully

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is pretty old but I came across the same issue while trying to install Strapi on a Windows 10 local development enviroment using MySQL Database through npm, even though some of the posted answers in this thread helped me to get a better understanding of the issue for my specific case the solution was as follow:

**In phpMyAdmin**

1. Create a new MySQL DB Schema and user for the project, this will be the Database and User to be entered during the `npx` installation process

**In Windows PowerShell (as admin)**

2. `npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project`
3. `cd my-project`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm run develop`

**These are the npm, node and MySQL version I used to install Strapi locally:**

- npm Vers. 6.14.17 check your version using `npm -v`
- node.js Vers. 14.20.0 check your version using `node -v`
- MySQL Vers. 10.4.24-MariaDB

Strapi should run by defult at `http://localhost:1337/admin`

*To change the port it would be needed to edit the .env file at your project root directory.*

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues, tried a bunch of stuff. Ran this code in the terminal and it solved all of my issues:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl -y
```